# What does the following Python code do?

Tags: python

```
tmp = dict(zip(listToAppend, x_test))
# x_test is a data vector imported earlier from a file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> listToAppend = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> x_test = [1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(listToAppend, x_test)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>> dict(zip(listToAppend, x_test))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take an example of `two` lists and understand it.

`zip` combines the two lists, and creates a `list` of `2-elements tuple` with elements from both the lists.

And then `dict` convert that `list` of `tuple` to a dictionary, with `1st element` of each tuple as `key` and 2nd value as value.

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> dict(zip(l1, l2))
{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}
>>>
```

If you combine `3 lists` using `zip`, you'll get a `list of 3-elements tuple`.

Also, if your lists are not of same size, then `zip` considers only the least size, and ignores the extra elements from the larger list.

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b']
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```